# correlation time series in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, correlation

I currently have a data set that looks as such (3 variables and a time series):

```
date       variable    value    
01/01/16      A         1000
01/01/16      B         800
01/01/16      C         10
01/02/16      A         2000
01/02/16      B         1800
01/02/16      C         100
01/03/16      A         100
01/03/16      B         80
01/03/16      C         10
```

What I'm trying to do is calculate the correlation between all three variables (A-B, A-C, B-C) per day so that I can graph the result as a plot with the date being on the x axis and on the y axis the correlation coefficient (w/ the legend being A-B, A-C, B-C).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Calculating a correlation per day doesn't make sense.

Comment: You could only calculate a correlation per-day per-pair (A-B, B-C, B-C) if you had multiple values for each A, B, and C, on that day. But your example data only has one point per day. Is that an oversight, or is that how your data actually looks?

Comment: only one point per variable per day...what would be the best way to represent this data so as to show that for instance, variables A and B are closely related, even on a daily basis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
df <- read.csv(sep=" ",stringsAsFactors=F,text="date variable value
01/01/16 A 1000
01/01/16 B 800
01/01/16 C 10
01/02/16 A 2000
01/02/16 B 1800
01/02/16 C 100
01/03/16 A 100
01/03/16 B 80
01/03/16 C 10 ")
df$date <- strptime(df$date, format = "%m/%d/%y")
df$value <- as.numeric(df$value)

vars <- unique(df$variable)
nv <- length(vars)
npairs <- nv*(nv-1)/2
labs <- rep("", npairs)
cors <- rep(0, npairs)
k <- 1
for (i in 1:(nv-1)) {
    vi <- vars[i]
    si <- df[df$variable == vi,]$value
    for (j in (i+1):nv) {
        vj <- vars[j]
        sj <- df[df$variable == vj,]$value
        labs[k] <- sprintf("%s-%s",vi,vj)
        cors[k] <- cor(si, sj)
        k <- k+1
    }
}
pdf <- data.frame(labs=labs,cors=cors)
ggplot(pdf) + geom_bar(aes(x=labs,y=cors),stat="identity")
```

yielding:
[image]

Comment: i see...so taking the correlation of each (A-B, A-C, and B-C) across multiple days?

Comment: Well, you can't take a correlation from a single point. You need at least two values to calculate a correlation, and frankly it doesn't make much sense until you have like 10 of them.

Comment: Thanks Mike! You were super helpful!

Comment: Great and thank you. Also when you get to 15 points, it would help if you came back and upvoted it as well, as that gives me credits to a silver ggplot2 badge.